# Create Download Link But Source is Java String

Tags: java, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to create a download link but the part I'm having trouble is that the source is a Java string. The String I have is a JSON data. I want people to be able to download that data.

I am using the Play! framework so I can pass the String data using the Scala template. But I'm not sure how to allow users to download the String and append the file types (.txt, .json) so that users actually download a file.

How do I go about to doing this?

Comment: You need to change the Content-disposition header to 'attachment'.  (Which I do not know how to do with Play!, hence can't give you an actual answer, but that might be enough info to find how to do it.)

Comment: Thanks for leading me into finding what I needed. I figure it out and the solution was actually very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe how simple the solution is. This was what did it for me. Basically take the string and convert it into an InputStream.

```
String data = "someBigOrSmallData";

InputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());

response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=anyFileName.txt");

return ok(dataStream);
```